# Create an audio data programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

Hi can anyone help me how to create an audio data programmatically.

I know how to play sound files on my resources, but what I need is a silent audio that I can play flexibly(adjust its length) on AVAudioPlayer.

Can anyone point on some resources or keyword that I need to look up about these.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

when using a signed sample format with an uncompressed audio signal, silent audio data is simply a stream of zero filled samples:

```
for (size_t idx = 0; idx < sampleCount; ++idx) {
  sampleBuffer[idx] = 0;
}
```

so you can use that approach to mute a stream or create a resource (e.g. file) from a buffer you produce.